# Ubuntu 12.04 stopped to lock screen after X minutes

Tags: 12.04, screen, lock, idle

My **Ubuntu 12.04** suddenly stopped to auto-lock after X minutes. It doesn't matter how long I leave the computer idle, it NEVER turns the screen off and never locks the screen either.

I am using **Gnome-shell**. Under the `Brightness and Lock` menu, I have marked:

- Dim screen to save power
- Turn screen off when idle for 5 minutes
- Lock screen after 5 minutes

I have already re-installed **gnome-screensaver** (no effect). Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt-get purge gnome-screensaver`, and then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver`?

Comment: @cgubuntu1204, no success... purged gnome-screensaver and reinstalled it. Seems to have no effect. Still wont lock the screen.

Comment: Did it used to work? Did you do something recently that could cause this?

Comment: It used to work. I have done nothing besides update-manager... Also, i have noticed that it is not related to GNOME, because even if i login on Unity interface, it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

Start the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and then type:

1. `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
2. Start dconf-editor
3. UnCheck(if the option check means) org->gnome->desktop->lockdown-> disable-lock-screen (for verify - goto System settings->Brightness & Lock: check the Lock option enable or not).
4. Close the editor.
5. Restart the system & see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps easier method of user1709672's response is to open terminal (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T`), and type this:
`sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool`

Once installed, open it by locating it in your application menu of choice by searching "Unity Tweak tool" (or from terminal/Alt-F2 box by typing `unity-tweak-tool`). Then, click the security button (I think it defaults to look like a little castle with marbles bouncing away from it), and make sure the "Disable Screen Lock" and perhaps "Disable User Switching"/"Disable User Log Out" options are unchecked. If there's a "Disable Display Sleep" option on yours, uncheck that as well.
If non are checked, perhaps try checking and unchecking each one (sometimes, when this program goes in to change the configs, it can overwrite a mistakenly changed one, and then changing it back gets you to the target config).

Restart and see if this works. Also, try manually inducing the lock window with `Ctrl` +  `Alt` + `L`.